# ToolStripMenuItem and ToolStrip Button in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

How to code ToolStripMenuItem to execute the corresponding function.

```
 Public Overridable Function CalcEndingBalance() As Double
 Dim B As Double
 B = p - A * n
    Return B                                  
End Function
```

This is function that is to be executed.

```
Private Sub CalculateToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)    Handles CalculateToolStripMenuItem.Click
```

...............*

End Sub

I am having trouble figuring out the code to invoke the function.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far so that we have some direction concerning your intentions.

Answer (score 0):

`CalcEndingBalance` is a function, which returns a Double, so you'll have to figure out what to do with the return value, but here's a quick example of how to display a MessageBox with the result. I also cleaned up your function a little.

```
Public Overridable Function CalcEndingBalance() As Double
    Return p - A * n
End Function

Private Sub CalculateToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)    Handles CalculateToolStripMenuItem.Click
    MessageBox.Show(CalcEndingBalance().ToString)
End Sub
```

You could also do something like set another variable:

```
    Dim endingBal As Double = 0
    endingBal = CalculateBalance()
```

or populate a TextBox:

```
    TextBox1.Text = CalculateBalance().ToString
```